# Согласование слова "зовут" с именем

Tags: падежи

Как правильно: 
Вас зовут Владимир Михайлович. Или: Вас зовут Владимиром Михайловичем. Зовут - требует вопроса "как?" (им. п.) или "кем?" (тв. п.)

Answer (score 3):

Варианты, понятно, равнозначны, но вот равноноупотребительны ли?

Меня зовут как? - Иван.
Меня зовут кем? - Иваном.

Раньше оно так и воспринималось, сейчас первый вариант потихоньку вытесняет второй. Форма с творительным падежом воспринимается как разговорная или архаичная.

Но вообще конкуренция "Именительный vs Творительный" наблюдается у целого ряда глаголов.
Возьмите хотя бы "Он был титулярный советник" против "Итак, она звалась Татьяной".
Подробное обсуждение этого процесса опускаю, увело бы слишком далеко от темы.

Comment: >XXIV  
Ее сестра звалась Татьяна...  
Впервые именем таким  
Страницы нежные романа  
Мы своевольно освятим. 
..............................  
XXV  
Итак, она звалась Татьяной.   
Ни красотой сестры своей,  
Ни свежестью ее румяной   
Не привлекла б она очей.

Comment: >Разговор уже был  
  
Вы тоже уже обещали удалиться с ресурса раз и навсегда. Что из этого?
По Вашей ссылке нет слова "равнозначно".

Answer (score 0):

Равнозначно :

> В. В. Куйбышев. Эпизоды из моей жизни (1930-1935) (и я и он в организации были под чужими именами и настоящих имен друг друга не знали). Я говорю, что **меня зовут Андреем**. ― Вот, ― говорит, ― странно.
>
> Михаил Рыбьянов. Валентин Дикуль: «Цирк серьезно болен» (2002) // «Известия», 2002.04.17 ― Валентин Иванович, здравствуйте, вас из Питера беспокоят. **Меня зовут Андрей**. Я занимаюсь ресторанным бизнесом.